# How do I stretch my object from one point to the other?

Tags: modeling

[image]
Just wondering how I could get my object (the truss) to stretch and become the same size and shape like the cube behind it.

Thanks.

Comment: scaling along one axis seems obvious, why it's not working?

Comment: Mostly because the truss itself is at an angle. (Like 5 degrees on the z-axis)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this with snapping and transforms with cursor as pivot. I tried to rebuild a situation similar to what I see in your picture, so that the truss is of different size and rotation than the other shape:

[image]

First of all, switch to top view, and activate vertex snapping like below:

[image]

Then, translate the truss towards the other shape, and snap a corner vertex as below:

[image]

Then, go into edit mode (of the truss) and select one corner vertex, then snap the 3D cursor to it.

[image]

Now you can activate cursor pivoting, and rotate the truss

[image]

...until its upper vertex snaps to the other shape, perfectly:

[image]

Now the different angle is gone, and you can switch to front view, to stretch (scaling) the truss until it matches (snapping) the other shape perfectly:

[image]

Does this solve your issue?